# Swift passing array values from one viewcontroller to another

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

My Scenario, I am loading `JSON` data into `tableView`, whenever I am trying to click `tableView` custom `cell` I am getting cell `indexPath.row` data. Now, I am trying to pass particular cell `array` data to another `viewcontroller`. Here, I need to `verify` below code is correct one or not and also how to get all the `values` from array and to show on `labels` in second `viewcontroller`?

Here below code to passing array value one to another viewcontroller

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(self.tableArray[indexPath.row])
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let smallVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popupview")  as! PopupViewController
    let item = tableArray[indexPath.row]
    smallVC.array = [item]
    present(smallVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Second ViewController

```
var array = [Datum]() //Datum decodable root

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(“DATA: \(array)") //here, i need to get all values and assign label.
}
```

My Output

> DATA: [parseJSON.Datum(catID: "3", catName: "Cars", catParentid: "2",
>   name: “jhon”, year: "3000", fullname: parseJSON.Fullname(firstname:
>   "jio", lastname: "jack"), address: parseJSON.Address(city:
>   "sanfrancisco", state: "california"), ship: parseJSON.Ship(captian:
>   "mojo", time: "12.30.01"))]

Comment: As you get this output, the code is correct. Please add the information which values are supposed to be displayed on which labels. And actually you pass **one** item, it's not an array.

Comment: I need to get catID and firstname from inside output array then need to show on label.@vadian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `item` is **one** object of the array. An array is pointless.

```
smallVC.item = item
```

and in Second ViewController

```
var item : Datum!
```

You get `catID` and `firstname` with

```
let catID = item.catID
let firstname = item.fullname.firstname
```

---

It's very easy to figure out the data structure yourself: type `item.` and see what Xcode suggests.

Comment: wow fentastic. if I want to send this data from second to third view controller what I want to do? second vc present model if I dismiss I am moving my tab index directly to second tab. @vadian

Comment: That's another question.